How to make data storage in Minecraft Plugins?
I'm trying to make a plugin for ranked parkour but im stuck at some point. I wanted players do some parkours, for example parkour 1, and after finish the parkour they can go parkour 2 but not parkour 3 without finishing parkour 2. So I decided I need to store the data of players' current parkour and reading it for accessing the parkour. But here is the where im stuck. I don't know which method to use store these datas. I searched for yaml storage on internet but im kinda lost there.
How can I do it?

As you said, you can use YAML formatting. You can also use external storage as MySQL.
Yaml is preferable if you want to have an easy way to manage it, and to be self-contained (not requiring external install).
In this example, we will have parkours.yml. So, you need to have
To do it, you have to :

Create the empty config file if not exists.

File configFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "parkours.yml"); // plugin var is your plugin instance
if (!configFile.exists()) { // file doesn't exist
    configFile.createNewFile(); // create empty file
}

If you want to copy a file to have pre-configured content, check here.

Load the yaml file

You simply have to do:
YamlConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);

If you don't found those class, check for library.

Interact with config.

You can use config.set("my-key", "my-val"); and retrieve it with config.getString("my-key"). In your case, it can be something like:
List<String> completedParkours = config.getStringList(uuid.toString());
// all parkours name's

completedParkours.add("parkour-3");
config.set(uuid.toString(), completedParkours);
// config changed BUT NOT SAVED


After edit, save the config

To save the config, you simply have to do config.save(configFile)
Final example code:
private static YamlConfiguration config;

public static YamlConfiguration getParkourConfig() {
    return config;
}

@Override
public void onEnable() { // in your on enable method
    try {
        configFile = new File(plugin.getDataFolder(), "parkours.yml");
        if (!configFile.exists()) {
            configFile.createNewFile();
        }
        config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void save() { // to save the config
    try {
        config.save(configFile);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

Somewhere else, in your code
public void playerFinishParkour(Parkour parkour, Player p) {
   YamlConfiguration config = MyPlugin.getParkourConfig();
   List<String> completedParkours = config.getStringList(p.getUniqueId().toString());
   completedParkours.add(parkour.getName());
   config.set(p.getUniqueId().toString(), completedParkours);
   MyPlugin.save();
}

Some recommendation

I think it's better to make a specific class to load the file, and save it
You can use multiple content in the config to precise all informations you want, with config.set(uuid.toString() + ".parkours", completedParkours)
Do not forget to save the file

